# Post to facebook page via PHP

Tags: php, facebook

Having looked through all the developer pages on facebook and about a million out of date tutorials on google, I cannot find a simple way to post to a facebook page (note, this is a fan page, not a personal one) via PHP. I do not need to get contacts or images or anything like that. I will be updating a blog every so often and I just want to post a link to each post on facebook automatically.

Does anyone have an up to date tutorial for this?

Answer (score 2):

Why just don't import your blog with a feed: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/02/22/how-to-import-your-blog-into-facebook/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something I wrote on [updating the news feed in PHP](http://sudocode.net/article/318/update-facebook-news-feed-using-the-graph-api-in-php/).

Comment: Please don't leave answers that are just links. Links change over time and break answers. You should include the relevant excerpt from the article in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use special services like [deliverIt](http://support.delivr.com/home) if you do not want to mess around with the FaceBook API yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using RSSGraffitti for it. However, I did not know of the existance of dlvr.it and as it looks much nicer to use I may change it.